# How to use ORM in android

Tags: java, android

I have to use ORM in android. I have read about the ORM from that I have understood that It is layer between Front end and Back End Database. Can any one please tell what is mean by ORM and how to use in android program. What is the advantage to use the ORM.

Comment: Please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493605/how-can-i-use-ormlite-with-androids-default-sqlite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ORM solutions for Android have already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development). [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is a good starting point. An ORM stands for Object Relational Mapping and will map database tables to entities. For a Persons table for example, a class Person will be created. You will then be able to edit the fields of the class and when you call a "save" method, the database table will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development) previous SO post in which they discuss what you need. You can find the definition of what an ORM is on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

It basically allows you make code which is database independent (among other advantages), so you can switch databases and all you need to do is a minor configuration rather than changing all your query statements.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try using above reference.